# Переход предствавлений: как правильно сделать через transitionFromView?

Tags: xcode, objective-c

При Алерте перехожу с SecondViewController на FirstViewController таким методом:

```
- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonAlertIndex
{
    if (alertView.tag ==3) //выйгрышный алерт
    {
        FirstViewController *fvc = [[FirstViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:fvc animated:YES];      
    }
}
```

Но хочу поменять стиль перехода, как это сделать? Мне подсказали что можно  через transitionFromView,
нарыл код:

```
[UIView transitionFromView:view2 toView:view1 duration:2.0
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                completion:nil];
```

Но прикрутить не знаю как. что писать вместо view1 и view2 ?
имею такие файлы: 
FirstViewController.h
FirstViewController.m
FirstViewController.xib
SecondViewController.h
SecondViewController.m
SecondViewController.xib

Подскажите люди добрые)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод transitionFromView нужен для смены вьюх, у вас же смена презентации контроллеров. Тем более NavigationController`ов.

Посмотрите решине для NavigationController`a [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5889757/887325) .Хотя оно подойдет для любых анимаций.

Comment: работает)) спасибо!! а что такое "For Pop" ? это в айпэде?))

Comment: `UINavigationController ` почитайте документацию. Он имеет два ключевыйх метода: `pushViewController:animated:` и `popViewControllerAnimated:`